How can I inlcude .jrxml file in my maven-assembly-plugin build
I am trying to build my maven project with maven-assembly plugin, but one thing I notice is the .jrxml file doesnt include in classpath, how can I inlude my jasperreport .jrxml file in my class path using maven-assembly-plugin build
here is my build in pom.xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.kmdpos.Kmdpos</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   
</build>

It runs but when I inspect the jar file, it doesnt include .jrxml file, because of that I cannot generate print reports of my jasper reports
